# set hanging indent for more than one paragraph at a time

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

is there a way to start every paragraph in a document with a hanging indent, without defining this for each and every paragraph? 
Is this possible without any extra packages loaded or such?

And, while we're at it: is it possible to start an area of, say, 10 out of 100 paragraphs in a row, with a hanging indent, where the rest of the paragraphs don't start with a hanging indent?

EDIT:

So I want is: 10 paragraphs with hanging indent, 90 paragraphs without hanging indent. Is this accomplishable:

- without defining this for every paragraph separately
- loading extra packages

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The question is very broad. May you make some examples of what you're asking?

Comment: The problem is in what your paragraphs are supposed to contain: LaTeX plays with `\parshape` when doing lists or environments such as `center`, so they don't go along with the primitives for hanging indentation. For plain text the thing can be easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sure it is possible by some TeX programming. On the other hand, the [hanging](https://ctan.org/pkg/hanging) package already does most of what you are asking for. Just put all body text, or any number of paragraphs to be hung, inside a `\hangparas` environment.

Answer (score 6):

This is a simple solution to your problem, when the paragraphs contain only text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}

\parindent=0pt
\newcounter{paras}
\everypar{%
  \stepcounter{paras}%
  \ifnum\value{paras}>10 
    \everypar{}
  \else
    \hangindent=5em \hangafter=1
  \fi}

\kant[1-100]

\end{document}
```

The mysterious `\everypar` is a container of tokens that are inserted whenever a paragraph is started. In this case we say to step the counter and look at its value: at the moment its value is greater than 10, we are at the 11th paragraph, so we remove everything from `\everypar`, otherwise we set the hanging indentation.

Comment: That will help me a lot at a later time, but thank you very much in advance for your effort and in the name of those who already fully understand all this code. Really, thanks!
I'm a newbie to LaTex, loving what I found so far and looking forward to what comes. This here is a huge promise :)