# hanging indent in RTL

Tags: indentation, bidi

I have a RTL Arabic doc.  Because I want most of these to have a hanging indent, I don't want to wrap each paragraph in a special environment.  Instead I want to be able to turn on and turn off hanging indent throughout the doc.

I thought maybe I could use `\everypar`, I got the idea from @egreg's answer in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60613/set-hanging-indent-for-more-than-one-paragraph-at-a-time), but I can't get this simple MWE to work: the indentation still happens on the left, not the right, as you can see [image: here].

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\everypar{\hangindent=5em \hangafter=1}

كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 

\end{document}
```

Comment: try with `\everypar{\hangindent=-5em \hangafter=1}`

Comment: Here is a solution using `arabluatex` and `enumitem` https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695297/16493