# \hangindent and RTL text

Tags: indentation, right-to-left, bidi

while \hangindent works perfectly for left to right text, it does not work for RTL text, with bidi.

Cf this example running with xelatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
\begin{hebrew}
  \parindent=0em
\hangindent=4em
\hangafter=1
בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃
וְהָאָ֗רֶץ הָיְתָ֥ה תֹ֨הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵ֣י תְהֹ֑ום וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם׃
וַיֹּ֥אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֖ים יְהִ֣י אֹ֑ור וַֽיְהִי־אֹֽור׃
יַּ֧רְא אֱלֹהִ֛ים אֶת־הָאֹ֖ור כִּי־טֹ֑וב וַיַּבְדֵּ֣ל אֱלֹהִ֔ים בֵּ֥ין הָאֹ֖ור וּבֵ֥ין הַחֹֽשֶׁךְ׃
\end{hebrew}

  \parindent=0em
\hangindent=4em
\hangafter=1
1Au commencement Dieu créa le ciel et la terre.
2La terre était un chaos, elle était vide ; il y avait des ténèbres au-dessus de l'abîme, et le souffle de Dieu tournoyait au-dessus des eaux.
3Dieu dit : Qu'il y ait de la lumière ! Et il y eut de la lumière.
4Dieu vit que la lumière était bonne, et Dieu sépara la lumière et les ténèbres
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `\hangindent < 0` to indent from the right. I notice it also needs `\par` (or empty line) at end of Hebrew paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{SBL BibLit}[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate]
\begin{document}
\begin{hebrew}
  \parindent=0em
  \hangindent=-4em
  \hangafter=1
  בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃
  וְהָאָ֗רֶץ הָיְתָ֥ה תֹ֨הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵ֣י תְהֹ֑ום וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם׃
  וַיֹּ֥אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֖ים יְהִ֣י אֹ֑ור וַֽיְהִי־אֹֽור׃
  יַּ֧רְא אֱלֹהִ֛ים אֶת־הָאֹ֖ור כִּי־טֹ֑וב וַיַּבְדֵּ֣ל אֱלֹהִ֔ים בֵּ֥ין הָאֹ֖ור וּבֵ֥ין הַחֹֽשֶׁךְ׃

\end{hebrew}

\parindent=0em
\hangindent=4em
\hangafter=1
1Au commencement Dieu créa le ciel et la terre.
2La terre était un chaos, elle était vide ; il y avait des ténèbres au-dessus de l'abîme, et le souffle de Dieu tournoyait au-dessus des eaux.
3Dieu dit : Qu'il y ait de la lumière ! Et il y eut de la lumière.
4Dieu vit que la lumière était bonne, et Dieu sépara la lumière et les ténèbres
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: indeed, that work, but that implies a different treatment weather your are on RTL or on LTR. So with more complex example (as on https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477099/7712, that would be problematic)

Comment: @Maïeul: weather ≠ whether.

Comment: @Maïeul, I just worked out you can use a negative value for `\hangindent`. Could you set the sign inside your `\hangindentX{…}` macro based on current text direction?

Comment: @Maïeul, e.g., if you redefine `\normalfootfmtX` (and your other macros that use `\hangindent`) to test `\if@RTL` and then change sign of `\hangindent` you can get the output you want in the other question.

Comment: @Maïeul, something like this: `\if@RTL
    \hangindent=-\csuse{hangindentX@#1}%
    \everypar{\hangindent=-\csuse{hangindentX@#1}}%
  \else
    \hangindent=\csuse{hangindentX@#1}%
    \everypar{\hangindent=\csuse{hangindentX@#1}}%
  \fi`

Comment: hoho @DavidPurton. Thanks for the tips. I will implement it soon. I prefere that to the previous

Answer (score 0):

Using `arabluatex` and `enumitem`, here is a MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\usepackage{arabluatex}

\usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlist{hangar}{itemize}{1}
    \setlist[hangar]{label={},itemindent=-2em,leftmargin=2em}

\begin{document}
\Huge

\begin{arab}
\begin{hangar}
\item 
kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt 
kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt  

\item
kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt 
kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt kalimAt  
\end{hangar}
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

[image: RTL hanging indent sample]